# Exclusive microtubule minus-end labeling

Tags: proteins, fluorescent-microscopy

Like the title explains I am looking for a way to exclusively label microtubule minus end **in vivo**. Looking through the literature I could not find any techniques yet. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

γ-Tubulin is specifically [localized](http://jcb.rupress.org/content/131/1/207.full.pdf) to the minus end of microtubules. GFP labeled γ-Tubulin can be used to label the minus ends in-vivo and without the requirement of staining. [Fan et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283696903228) have developed a phage display antibody specific to α-Tubulin that can be used to visualize minus ends. See the figure below.

[image]

The image is an electron-micrograph but it is certainly possible to do a fluorescent microscopy after IHC staining.